# Sails.js - authentication both with session and token

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, authentication, sails.js

I'm building app with `sails` framework and some parts of it requires authentication based on `session` (like going to some pages of app). But I don't have a lot of cases when session based auth is needed. Most of app is based on single page with angular connecting with server `RESTful` way so there I need token based auth.

There is no many resources explaining how to do it.

[here](http://lowbrowcoder.me/2015/04/10/sails-0-11-and-passport-sails-auth-generater-coming-from-rails/) it's explained how to do REST based auth, and [here](https://www.bearfruit.org/2014/07/21/tutorial-easy-authentication-for-sails-js-apps/) it's explained for session based auth.

Anyone of you know some example how to 'merge' both of those methods?

Comment: why are you not using passport.js for authentication? It supports token based auth also https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens and http://passportjs.org/docs are good to start from